# Hide out-of-boundary part of `UITableViewCell`

Tags: ios, uitableview

Just like CSS's `overflow: none;`, how can I hide the out-of-boundary part of `UITableViewCell`? and show certain components in cell only when it is selected?

I was thinking hiding & showing the elements using `UITableViewDelegate` methods, but I can't work it out quite well. I used the followings:

```
NSIndexPath  *selected_index;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  selected_index = indexPath;
  [cell.web_view setHidden:NO];
  [tableView beginUpdates];
  [tableView endUpdates];
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section) {
  if(selected_index != nil && selected_index.row == indexPath.row) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TestCell"];
    [cell.web_view setHidden:NO];
    return 250;
  }
  [cell.web_view setHidden:YES];
  return 74;
}
```

where `cell.web_view` is a `UIWebView` which has height (200) larger than the table cell (74).  But the codes didn't make the web view shows up & hide properly.

What can I do alternatively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest code for `overflow: none` is `[cell setClipsToBounds:YES];`

To hide and show things when tapped you should have a few variables like
`BOOL shouldShowMyWebViews;`, and toggle their state in `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you could show or hide your elements just before returning the cell.